How to copy and paste files or folders based on modified timestamp range in one s3 location to another s3 location using AWS CLI
I am having some data files in a AWS s3 location across different sub-directories. When normally these files are received, AWS Event notification will be triggered and these files will be processed by another Lambda. But due to some issue in Lambda, some days files are not processed.
As the Lambda issue is resolved, I want to trigger the AWS event notification to process these pending files. I want to copy these pending files for the last couple of days and paste them in the same location to process them.
I tried the below AWS CLI command to copy the files in the same location
aws s3api list-objects --bucket <my-bucket> --prefix <folder1/Folder1-1/> --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2024-03-13T00:00:00' && LastModified<='2024-04-29T23:59:59'].{Key: Key}" --output text | xargs -I {} aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/{} my-bucket/{}
But the above code block is pasting the files one by one with different modified timestamp('LastModified'). This is causing the Lambda to get triggered multiple times which is not desired.
Can anyone please suggest how to edit the above command so that a single AWS notification will be triggered for all the files copied.
I need a single liner code

I don't think this would be possible. The LastModified is an actual timestamp from when the object is created, which will be different for each object as it is copied on top of itself. Could you instead write some code to invoke the Lambda function with a 'fake' payload that contains the list of objects exactly as if it was triggered by S3, but you are manually triggering it with the same information? It would just be a matter of creating the JSON payload. You could even run it from the Test option in the Lambda management console (unless there is some size limitation on the JSON.)
